# Cannot use pyinstaller because of cffi.api.CDefError

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller, cffi

Can anyone have a look what goes wrong with my pyinstaller?

I also tried to convert a .py file to .exe file, but the same error was generated

Update. 12/15. BTW, I have installed both python 2.7 and python 3 on my computer, would that be the problem?

However, I have tried install pyinstaller under C:\Python27\Scripts to try to avoid the conflict between 2 pythons. (I am not sure if this could still cause the problem but I just try to list all the details I know for the question.)

New update. 12/16. I have tried to move my target file (to convert) to the script folder, where pyinstaller is installed, the file will be converted successfully. But the script folder will be messed up because multiple folders and files will be generated.

I have added the problem that generated from cmd below :)

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2018.8.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (28.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (1.11)
Requirement already satisfied: dis3 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.17.1)
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller
Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.4

C:\Python27\Scripts>pyinstaller
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 212, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.pywin32 import pywintypes  # noqa: F401
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.pywin32 import win32api
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 12, in <module>
    from win32ctypes.core import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\__init__.py", line 36, in load_module
    module = importlib.import_module(self.redirect_module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 19, in <module>
    """)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 107, in cdef
    self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, packed=packed)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 167, in parse
    self._internal_parse(csource)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 173, in _internal_parse
ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 130, in _parse
self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\cparser.py", line 159, in convert_pycparser_error
    raise api.CDefError(msg)
cffi.api.CDefError: cannot parse "HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibraryExW(LPCTSTR lpFileName, HANDLE hFile, DWORD dwFlags);"
:16:16: before: LoadLibraryExW
```

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768797/pyinstaller-3-4-not-working-on-windows-10-with-python-2-7

Comment: should be tagged : cffi, windows

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade the `cffi` by using below command:

```
pip install --upgrade cffi
```

Comment: and pip3 install --upgrade cffi       for python 3